# Create invoices in CiviCase

Tags: wordpress, civicase, invoice

We are still evaluating CiviCRM 5.4.1 and CiviCase on Wordpress 4.9.8

Most of our requirements can be filled by CiviCRM and CiviCase.

But one requirement is to have invoices listed and followed up in case summaries.

I found that we can generate invoices in Contributions and Events which would suit our need to generate invoices.

But I can't get them listed in a case summary/activities.

Does anybody know how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two comments:

1. CiviCRM is not really good in invoicing. So my advice would be to do the invoicing part in a seperate system, usually an accounting software might do the job
2. I have made an extension to link Contributions to a case, check it out at: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.casecontribution

May I ask what exactly you want to invoice from the case?

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
We do realize that invoicing is not a strength of CiviCRM.
And it seems you extension will do the trick to have all information in one place.

Not all of our cases are non-profit and therefore we need to issue invoices.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Contribution cannot be linked to Case in current version of CiviCRM (5.4.1) but you can build an extension where you can link contribution to Civicase either by assigning Invoice activity to case or through custom entity table.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I will add it to the list of customization to be developed.

Comment: Cheers! All the best.